# gitattributes - how to identify bash script files with no extension

Tags: git, bash, gitattributes

I'm just getting up to speed with using git. I've been using the examples in https://github.com/Danimoth/gitattributes to put together a gitattributes file for my various projects (mostly bash and python scripts). My problem is that most of my bash scripts have no file extension. Is there a pattern I can use to explicitly select these (e.g. for a filter)? Or would it be easier to rename them with an .sh extension?

Comment: I have been using `git` for well over five years across probably hundreds of projects and I think only once have I ever need a `.gitattributes` file.  Looking at that repository, I'm not sure what value you think you're getting there.  I think you are just needlessly complicating your life.  `git` will generally figure out text vs. binary all by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So if I apply a smudge or clean filter to a project git will always skip those it thinks are binary?

Comment: @KeithWatson Correct - git will attempt to identify files as binary by itself.  You're safe to say something like `* text=auto` and that will try _not_ to do terribly things to binary files.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but it seems like you could work `head -n 1 * | grep '#!/bin/bash'` (or equivalent) into some command, couldn't you?  Would post as comment, but reputation isn't high enough.

Hopefully I haven't completely misinterpreted your query.